# If Cursor Result Set is Empty Return Something

Tags: mysql, if-statement, cursor

Is it possible to display something if result set in MySQL cursor is empty?
i.e.

If present, display result set based on the query
Else display 
column1 (null), column2 (category:general)...

Comment: Another method I am using now is:
`BEGIN
END;` if you don't like to display anything including null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. it is possible. Your code segment should be look like this.

```
if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
    //do something to print the column element
}else{
    // do something to print the column are empty
}
```

> EDIT

```
OPEN cursor_var;
select FOUND_ROWS() into numOfRows ;
```

Comment: if this answer really helps you, please don't forget to upvote the answer. cause it becomes helpful to the other person also. :)

Comment: do we have getcount function for mysql?

Comment: nope. actually i have shown you the structure of your expected code. it's just a pattern. but you can count the rows in a sql command. i will add this command into the EDIT section.

Comment: Thank you @sayem040. This basically answers my query.